# Getting "Invalid JSON sent in the Webhook notification" Authorize.net

Tags: php, authorize.net, authorize.net-webhooks

My Authorize.net webhook is set up properly on the A.net side, and when I trigger an event to get the notification, I get this in the error log:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception
>   'JohnConde\Authnet\AuthnetInvalidJsonException' with message 'Invalid
>   JSON sent in the Webhook notification' in /.../AuthnetWebhook.php:67
>   Stack trace:
>   0 /.../webhook.php(23): JohnConde\Authnet\AuthnetWebhook->__construct('xxxxxxxxxxx...', '',
>   Array)
>   1 {main}   thrown in /.../AuthnetWebhook.php on line 67

I can successfully setup the webhook and get notification history through the library on Github. Here is the code I'm using as my endpoint. Both allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include are set to enabled on my server.

```
<?php

namespace myapplication;

use JohnConde\Authnet\AuthnetWebhook;

require('.../config.inc.php');

require('.../autoload.php');

$headers = getallheaders();
$payload = file_get_contents("php://input");
$webhook = new AuthnetWebhook(AUTHNET_SIGNATURE, $payload, $headers);
if ($webhook->isValid()) {

    $transactionId = $webhook->payload->id;

    $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($webhook));
    fclose($fp);


    // Access notifcation values
    // echo $webhook->eventType;
}



?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Your payload is an empty string.. you can see it in the error.

```
AuthnetWebhook->__construct('xxxxxxxxxxx...', '', Array)
```

So

```
new AuthnetWebhook(AUTHNET_SIGNATURE, $payload, $headers);
```

I am not familiar with `AuthnetWebhook` but I would bet (if I was a gambler) that the payload variable should not be empty.

Comment: Yeah, that's part of what I don't understand. I believe the $payload should be the JSON data I'm receiving from the webhook.

Comment: it may be put in `$_POST` sometimes it goes in there, but I think it should still be in `://input` even so.  I would output or save the input, from that an the Post data, you can save post in a file by using `var_export($_POST, true);` to get it as a formatted string.  And then use `file_put_contents`  I know sometimes hooks and things are hard to see the output from, so saving it to file is a option there.

Comment: Most ppl don't realize var_export has a second optional argument, that returns it as a string instead of outputting it... :)  but It should not be empty so the obvious things are, A. its not being sent, B. it not where you think it is.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that to see what I'm getting back.

Comment: When I do the var_export all I get is array ( ) in the test.txt file. Back to the drawing board...

Comment: No, that is expected if `$_POST` is empty.  So in conclusion, the data is never reaching your page, as to why that is I don't know enough about it to tell you, but it's probably an error upstream, and this page is not the problem.

Comment: So while we don't yet have the answer, we know far more then we did before.

Comment: You're right that the `$payload` is empty and it definitely shouldn't be. `$_POST` should be empty so that result is expected. Have you tried testing your implementation by using a tool like Postman to simulate a webhook? That would be a good way to test if you're script is functioning properly.

Comment: Have not tried Postman. Downloading that now. Like I said above, using your Github page, I can successfully set up the webhook and get the notification history. Just struggling with this part.

Comment: Using requestb.in, I get the correct RAW BODY data from the webhook. Not sure where that leaves me. Only thing I can think is that the file_get_contents isn't working...

Comment: What do you mean by this, specifically `I get the correct RAW BODY data from the webhook` are you saying you get the correct input data when you post to it.  That would say that file_get_contents works fine.  You cant get something from nothing.

Comment: When I switch the endpoint URL to a requestb.in url, I get the JSON data I need. When the endpoint URL is the one on my server, file_get_contents doesn't return anything. That's why $payload is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The endpoint URL was incorrect. I had mysite.com/webhook.php and needed www.mysite.com/webhook.php.

Comment: subdomain, you can forward that to mysite.com in cpanel... fyi, one of the first things I always do.